# JavaScript: Show Difference between to date, as remaind time. (what about same day and before)

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I want to show the difference between today and selected date time to show the remained time.

I used the solution mentioned in stack overflow. But I have problem about today!
When the selected day is today, or before, I mean, when the difference (`diffDays`) is not positive, I get wrong result. How can I manage this?

```
 $("#ServiceTime").change(
    function (e) {
        var firstDate = $(this).val();
        var secondDate = new Date();
        var diffDays = firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime();
        var date = new Date(diffDays);
        var str = '';
        str += date.getUTCDate()-1 + " days and ";
        str += date.getUTCHours() + " hours and  ";
        str += date.getUTCMinutes() + " minutes";
        str += "remained...";
        $("#remainedHourToService").html(str);
        });
```

UPDATED:
I can not use `abs` by itself, if user select two past day, again he will see '1 day and 58 minutes and... ' but I want '0 days and 0 minutes.... remained'.

Comment: I will be thankful if you would answer the problem or tell me why it needs down upvote

Comment: If you are going to calculate difference from now to some time in the past, then that result will be negative. If you just use absolute value, then you will get the actual difference.

Comment: Just put a conditional in to return 0's if the result is negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Math.abs() to get absolute value.

```
   $("#ServiceTime").change(function (e) {
        var firstDate = $(this).val();
        var second
        Date = new Date();
        var diffDays = Math.abs(firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime());
        var date = new Date(diffDays);
        var str = '';
        str += date.getUTCDate()-1 + " days and ";
        str += date.getUTCHours() + " hours and  ";
        str += date.getUTCMinutes() + " minutes";
        str += "has remained...";
        $("#remainedHourToService").html(str);
    });
```

UPDATE:

Easy to solve that issue. :)

```
  $("#ServiceTime").change(function (e) {
            var firstDate = $(this).val();
            var second
            Date = new Date();
            var diff = firstDate.getTime()-secondDate.getTime();
            var str2 = "";
            if(diff > 0) 
                str2 = "have remained...";
            else
                str2 = "have passed...";
            var diffDays = Math.abs(diff);
            var date = new Date(diffDays);
            var str = '';
            str += date.getUTCDate()-1 + " days and ";
            str += date.getUTCHours() + " hours and  ";
            str += date.getUTCMinutes() + " minutes";
            str += str2;
            $("#remainedHourToService").html(str);
        });
```